# How to update a record with dependency object with Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm studying `Entity Framework Core` version 8 using a `Blazor` project. The scenario is quite basic: I like to create a simple blog. I have an *Article* object that has 2 `ICollection` properties: *Category* and *Tags*

```
[Table("Articles")]
public class Article : Table
{
    [JsonPropertyName("body")]
    [JsonIgnore(Condition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull)]
    public string? Body { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Category>? Categories { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Tag>? Tags { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the class *Category* is defined like the following (*Tag* is similar)

```
[Table("tbl_Categories")]
public class Category : Table
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Article>? Articles { get; set; }
}
```

In the database, I have 3 tables: *Articles*, *Categories* and EF generates a linked table called *ArticleCategory*. This table is a link between the 2 main tables, but I don't have a representation in my code.

The issue starts when I want to update the *Article* object. If I pass the existing values for *Category*, I get this error

> An error occurred while saving the entity changes. See the inner exception for details.
> ---> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'PK_ArticleCategory'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'ArticleCategory'. The duplicate key value is (8, 15).

So, I think I have to delete this table first. I wrote this code to delete the records in the link table and then call for the update.

```
public void DeleteCategoriesByArticle(long id)
{
    var article = localDb?.Articles?
                          .Include(a => a.Categories)?
                          .Where(a => a.ID == id)
                          .FirstOrDefault();
    if (article != null)
    {
        bool hasChanges = false;

        if (article.Categories != null && article.Categories.Count() > 0)
        {
            article.Categories?.Clear();
            hasChanges = true;
        }

        if (hasChanges)
            localDb?.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

After that, I call the function for the update. In this case I get another error

> The instance of entity type 'Article' cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'ID'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities, ensure that only one entity instance with a given key value is attached. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values.

After a quick search, I changed how I retrieved the record

```
var article = localDb?.Articles?
                      .AsNoTracking()
                      .Include(a => a.Categories)?
                      .Where(a => a.ID == id)
                      .FirstOrDefault();
```

Now, I don't get the `Violation of PRIMARY KEY` error as before.

How can I update the *Article* record then?

### Update

This is my generic update

```
public void Update(T entity)
{
    _log.LogDebug($"[{nameof(T)}] Update an entity");
        
    if (entity == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(entity));

    if (entity.ModifiedAt == DateTime.MinValue)
        entity.ModifiedAt = DateTime.UtcNow;

    _db.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: *So, I think I have to delete this table first* -- No, this should be fixed in the update code. Please show that code.

Comment: If you learn EF Core, do not follow how to create Generic Repository. It is anti-pattern for EF Core.